# How to replace substring [ ] with a value X

Tags: java, json, data-structures

I have string as below in Java.

```
String Value = "You are my star [ ] dear";
```

I want just to remplace `[ ]` with value `X`.

Tried below. Nothing worked.

```
ReplaceAll("[]","X");
ReplaceAll("//[//]","X")
ReplaceAll("/[/]","X")
```

Comment: In Value, there's a space between [ and ], but no such space in what you've tried.

Comment: Also replaceAll takes a regex. `[` and`]` are special characters in regex and must be escaped by backslash. so `value.replaceAll("\\\[\s+\\\]")` should do the job

Comment: You got confused between forward slashes (/) (which have no special meaning) and backward slashes (\\) which do. Anyway, instead of using `replaceAll`, which uses regex, just use `replace` - it also replaces *all*.

Comment: What RealSkeptic said.  Stop using replaceAll;  it just makes the task more complicated than it needs to be.  Just use `value = value.replace("[ ]", "X");`.  Avoid regular expression usage.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 replace methods:

- `haystack.replace(needle, foo)`, which **replaces all** occurrences of `needle` with `foo` in the `haystack` string.
- `haystack.replaceAll(needle, foo)`, which **replaces all** occurrences of `needle` with `foo` in the `haystack` string just like `replace` does, except `needle` is treated as a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Note that `[]` has special meaning in this which is why what you're trying isn't working.
- `haystack.replaceFirst(needle, foo)`, which replaces only the first occurrence of `needle`, and also treats `needle` as a regular expression.

In addition, strings in java are immutable. You cannot change them. These methods don't change the string - they make you a new one with the changes applied. You have to do something with the result of this call.

Clearly then you want `replace` here:

```
String value = "You are my star [ ] dear";
String result = value.replace("[ ]", "X");
System.out.println(result);
```

That would print `You are my star X dear`.

Stuff that won't work:

```
String value = "You are my star [ ] dear";
value.replace("[ ]", "X"); // this doesn't work
System.out.println(value);
// still prints 'You are my star [ ] dear".
```

The above does not work because you have to assign the result of `replace` to something.

```
String value = "You are my star [ ] dear";
String value2 = value.replaceAll("[ ]", "X"); // this doesn't work
System.out.println(value2);
// prints 'YouXareXmyXstarX[X]Xdear".
```

This time it doesn't work because `[ ]` is regular expression-ese for 'a space', and thus, all spaces are replaced, which you didn't want.

```
String value = "You are my star [ ] dear";
String value2 = value.replaceAll("\\[ \\]", "X"); // okay...
System.out.println(value2);
```

This *does* work as that is the right regular expression for literally `[ ]`, but why complicate matters like this? Just use `replace`.